# Jquery - Access table values (tr children - td) and change them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Found a few posts about this but none answered my question properly.

I want to access some values in my table and change them using a click function in js using jquery. How can I access this and change it without using innerHTML?

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">Race</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">space holder lol</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
var tableArray = $("table").children().children();

    $("#input img.Majin").click(function() {
        //tableArray[0].innerHTML = "";

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following find function :

```
$("table").find('classname');
```